# Can we get Code Snippets?

Tags: feature-request

What I'd like to do is to create some simple-ish interactive puzzles with Javascript/CSS to get some feedback on a couple of different ideas I've got.

Is there any chance we can get [code snippets](http://cl.ly/image/19210z0M1d2R/Image%202014-12-05%20at%203.16.18%20pm.png) enabled on PSE? They're on SO already so shouldn't (?) take too much effort to enable on PSE. If not then I could always use JS Fiddle or something similar, it'd just be a lot easier for people to play around with if it were embedded into the question.

Comment: I'd personally be for this if we could restrict them to questions only, and not answers.

Comment: @Emrakul Is there any way we can find out? I have no idea what channel(s) you go through to get them enabled or configure them, etc

Comment: +1 useful. But @Emrakul why not for answers? Sometimes a puzzle-solving script would be good to share.

Comment: @AE That makes sense, but I was thinking more about overlap with PPCG (i.e. questions that ask for code in answers might be better elsewhere) - I see your point, though

Answer (score 6):

This would be a very useful feature, and not hard to implement. In fact, it was already implemented and perfectly functional, it is just a matter to activate it.

Someone may argue that this could make us overlap too much with PPCG. I disagree:

1. If someone post a PPCG question here, it is off-topic. Adding this feature would not change this fact.
2. The presence or absence of this feature do not makes a PPCG question on-topic.

Someone may also argue that this feature invites some sort of abuse. Again, I disagree:

1. If someone post a question containing javascript/css/whatever code and it is a valid puzzle, it really does not matters if this feature is available. But its availability just makes things easier.
2. If someone post a question that abuses the code-snippet feature, it would probably already be a bad question regardless the presence or absence of this feature.

Further, if someone really needs code for a puzzle question or for an answer, he/she can already just go to jsfiddle or ideone and post a link without this feature, or simply copy-and-paste it in the question/answer and ask for people to run it. So, the absence of this feature is not stopping anyone, but the presence would only makes things easier.

I really see no real reason against it.