# Does Puzzling support embedded YouTube videos?

Tags: support, formatting

Over on Meta Stack Exchange, SQB asked *[Which sites have YouTube embedding on?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/297500/351462)*

Searching on Puzzling Meta, I was able to find a post [requesting support for code snippets](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1645/34836), but found no mention of embedded YouTube videos. Additionally, [YouTube embedding is not shown in the markdown preview window](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/299082/351462), so there's no way to test without posting publically.

I originally planned on testing in *[The Riddle Sandbox](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5276/34836)*, but that doesn't seem to fall in line with the Sandbox's intended use.

**Are embedded YouTube videos supported on Puzzling?**

Comment: If you knew the answer, why ask the question. If it is something you want you could have just made the meta post about a feature request.

Comment: This question was my way of testing whether the feature was supported or not. I did not know the answer beforehand. (My answer containing the URLs was me testing)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the moment, it does not. If you *do* want it to support this, you should create a new meta post, with the tag [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request), and include a collection **of posts that would benefit from such a change**, there's a chance that we could support embedding YouTube videos.

Answer (score 3):

There's only one way to find out.

## Testing YouTube URL Embedding

**Regular** `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gocwRvLhDf8`

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gocwRvLhDf8

---

**Timestamped** `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gocwRvLhDf8&t=22`

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gocwRvLhDf8&t=22

---

**Shortened** `https://youtu.be/gocwRvLhDf8`

https://youtu.be/gocwRvLhDf8

---

**/Embed** `https://www.youtube.com/embed/gocwRvLhDf8`

https://www.youtube.com/embed/gocwRvLhDf8

---

**Embedded HTML** `<iframe width="854" height="480" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/gocwRvLhDf8" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>`

---

**Mobile** `https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=gocwRvLhDf8`

https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=gocwRvLhDf8

---

**Flash Player** `https://www.youtube.com/v/gocwRvLhDf8`

https://www.youtube.com/v/gocwRvLhDf8

---

**YouTube TV** `https://www.youtube.com/tv#/watch/video/idle?v=gocwRvLhDf8`

https://www.youtube.com/tv#/watch/video/idle?v=gocwRvLhDf8

---

<sub>See [*Which sites have YouTube embedding on?*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/298854/351462)</sub>